# Cron run exceeded the time limit and was aborted + How to change max_exec_time if not access on php.ini

Tags: 6, cron

I am running a script which Fetches the data from other site like `Articles` of a user and other things also. I run my script in `hook_cron`. Cron gives me this error after a while of script running.

`Cron run exceeded the time limit and was aborted`.

Also I don't have access to change php.ini and setting.php. How can I change `max_exec_time` value.

Comment: If you don't have access to anything that can change the max execution time, then you can't really change the max execution time.  Have you tried the [Batch API](http://drupal.org/node/180528) for your cron tasks?  Might be worth splitting the task up to prevent timeouts.

Comment: There's some more advice for using the Batch API in `hook_cron` [here](http://drupal.org/node/988192#comment-3847954).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted to my client and get Access to files.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you don't have access to anything that allows you to change the max execution time (and I would imagine if you find a workaround that it won't work if your server is this locked down) I see a couple of options.

1:  Utilise the Batch API as I mentioned in my comment (Batch API docs are [here](http://drupal.org/node/180528))

2: Check out [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) to split your cron tasks up into smaller, more manageable chunks.

> Elysia Cron extends Drupal standard cron, allowing a fine grain
>   control over each task and several ways to add custom cron jobs to
>   your site.

Comment: This is a much better idea than the nonsense I was spouting :)

Comment: I know this from personal experience :p On my live box if I try to change anything with `ini_set` outside of settings.php or php.ini then it won't *actually* work :(

Comment: @Chapabu I can't use Elysia Cron with poorman cron. Because Most of things are setup with poorman cron. I will check the Batch API. I didn't know anything about batch api so I have to read it first.

Comment: @Sumit Drupal also has built-in queue handling for cron jobs, check out [`hook_cron_queue_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7)

Comment: @SumitMadan That's a shame. Apparently [Ultimate Cron](http://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) works with Poormanscron, but I've never tried it, so I can't offer anything else other than the name.

Comment: @Chapabu Batch API is used for multiple process. But I have only one process that taking long time. Any other solution please?

Comment: @Chapabu Batch API is used for multiple process. But I have only one process that taking long time. Any other solution please?

Comment: @SumitMadan Can the one process not be split up?  If it's based on users you should be able to set a limit on sub-processes/queries within the batch API.

Comment: @SumitMadan From the sounds of it though, either this or Ultimate Cron are your only options as you sem to have zero access to *anything* that will allow you to change the `max_execution_time`.

Comment: @Chapabu No I can't. Because in my script It fetches the data of 1 user from other site. It deletes all the previous nodes and creates the new nodes. Which can be in 100s or 1000s. It doesn't runs even for a single user :(

Comment: @Chapabu I run that url of script using wget. But nothing changes? :(

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is another option for increasing max_execution_time, if you have access to that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739870/increase-max-execution-time-for-php.

Comment: not have access