# How do I increase the memory assigned to PHP?

Tags: 6

I have a script that saving the hundreds or thousands of nodes at one time and It is nearly impossible to manage it with `Batch API`. When I am running my script it saying :

> **Fatal error**: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16 bytes) in /home/staging-uls/www/sites/all/modules/token/token.module on line 461.

I set the memory using `ini_set('memory_limit','256M')`. My script is still so long that showing the error. Is there any other way to do so?

What my script is doing exactly:

1. It fetches a data from other site using cUrl. The data are articles, journals and some other user's data.
2. After getting the data in XML format, it adds each content.

Comment: If you could add *EXACTLY* what your script is trying to do, perhaps along with some code then it'd be easier to help.  Also, where are you using `ini_set(..)`, as your [previous question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53425/cron-run-exceeded-the-time-limit-and-was-aborted-how-to-change-max-exec-time-i) suggests you couldn't add this anywhere where it would work.

Comment: @Chapabu I talked to my client after that I set it. I set it in starting of menu's `page calback` function. I am updating my question with requirement.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wouldn't want to use the Batch API considering that it was built to meet this exact use-case?

Comment: @AmarnathRavikumar How will I manage the data coming from `Curl` Request using `Batch API`. Each time my script runs It fetches the data for Different Researcher. I have a content type of `Researcher`.

Comment: This question is off-topic, as it is asking how to increase the memory assigned to PHP, which is not a Drupal setting. The way of increasing the memory assigned to PHP doesn't change if you use Drupal, WordPress, Joomla, or plain PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) to unlimited and I used `output buffering` for keep my script in progress. Change the memory limit to `1024M`. I got it from [This URL](http://ckon.wordpress.com/2008/05/02/tricks-for-long-or-large-php-scripts/).

Comment: 1gb is pretty huge

Comment: @2-Stroker yeah. I thought maybe the problem was due to memory limit, but it was not.